# Unable to find a specification for a local (private) pod

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

I created two local pods: `MainPods` & `ChildPod` like this:

1. Create Framework (in Xcode)
2. `pod init & pod install` for MainPod & ChildPod
3. `pod spec create MainPod & pod spec create MainPod` (in their folders)
4. modify it

Then I inited pod in root folder of application:
 platform :ios, '13.0'

```
target 'PrivatePodBugDemo' do
    use_frameworks!
    # pod 'ChildPod', :path => 'DevPods/ChildPod'
    pod 'MainPod', :path => 'DevPods/MainPod'
end
```

[MainPod.podspec](https://github.com/ocbnishi/PrivatePodBugDemo/blob/master/DevPods/MainPod/MainPod.podspec)
[ChildPod.podspec](https://github.com/ocbnishi/PrivatePodBugDemo/blob/master/DevPods/ChildPod/ChildPod.podspec)

### What did you expect to happen?

I expected to all run good when I include **only** `MainPod` which already includes `ChildPod`.

### What happened instead?

This error happened
`[!] Unable to find a specification for ChildPod depended upon by MainPod`

It's disappears when I uncomment `pod 'ChildPod', :path => 'DevPods/ChildPod'` in app's Podfile.
But I need to not include ChildPod in app's Podfile.

### Project that demonstrates the issue

https://github.com/ocbnishi/PrivatePodBugDemo

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9803

Comment: Does it work if you only install the ChildPod?

Comment: @RedX
It works if i uncomment `pod 'ChildPod', :path => 'DevPods/ChildPod'` in app's Podfile.  Also ChildPod works well if I install ChildPod only.